# Sqlite 'Unrecognized token: ":" C++

Tags: c++, sql, string, sqlite

I'm not sure what to do with this as I can't remove the colon from my SQL string.
Basically I am trying to execute an SQL string in Sqlite using the below code.

```
    string database_name = "C:/Programs_C++/Project/Databases/dbase.db";

    string exec_string = "SELECT * FROM " + database_name + " WHERE type='table'";

    dbase_return=sqlite3_open_v2(database_name.c_str(),&db_handle,SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,NULL);


dbase_return_tbl=sqlite3_get_table(db_handle,exec_string.c_str(),&result,&row,&column,&error_msg);

    //But I get the error: unrecognized token: ":" ?
```

How do I get around this?  Thanks

Comment: `exec_string` is irrelevant here because you're not using it for anything.

Comment: Corrected.. I left a line out..Thanks

Comment: I do have a database with the name dbase.db .. Can you elaborate?  What should I have written here?  I can see that I may have that wrong now.  Can't select tables from a D'base this way?  Do you know how I should do it?  Thanks

Comment: You can `SELECT * FROM` a **table** but not from a database, unless it's some unusual SQLite extension I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have [URI filenames](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) switched on - this can be done at compile time or runtime (probably compile time for you if you didn't know about it).

If URI filenames are switched on, you need to change your filename to something like:

```
file:///C:/Programs_C++/Project/Databases/dbase.db
```

Edit: If you want to switch it off, I don't think you can do it for this one call (as the call takes a flag as part of the parameters which can only switch it on). Instead you can disable it globally by calling

```
sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI, 0)
```

which tells sqlite to disable the URI filename convention globally. Note: you only need to call this once and it is not thread safe, so probably just put this at the start of your program.

However, it might be worth investigating if URI filenames are useful to you before switching them off entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right there but I'm not sure how to use the SQLITE_USE_URI = 0 in my code.  I don't suppose you know how?  I have tried #define SQLITE_CONFIG_URI=0 at the top of my code with no luck

Comment: Thanks for that.. I just came across this too.  While it hasn't solved the issue it could have something to do with where I have put sqlite3_config so I'll keep trying.  I think you're on the right track though and it has given me a new consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You can `SELECT` from a ***table***, not from a database.

First open the database (using the filename), then execute a valid SQL statement like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

---

`SELECT * FROM C:/Programs_C++/Project/Databases/dbase.db WHERE type = 'table'` is not valid SQL. If you are trying to get a list of all tables, you cannot do it that way.